# What is err.(*os.PathError) in Go?

Tags: go

When I was reading: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#errors

I found such line: `err.(*os.PathError)` in this context:

```
for try := 0; try < 2; try++ {
    file, err = os.Create(filename)
    if err == nil {
        return
    }
    if e, ok := err.(*os.PathError); ok && e.Err == syscall.ENOSPC {
        deleteTempFiles()  // Recover some space.
        continue
    }
    return }
```

What exactly is `err.(*os.PathError)` in Go?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`os.Create` returns an error as second return value. The error itself is an [interface](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) `type error interface { Error() string }`. Any data type that happens to have a `Error` method will implement that interface and can be assigned.

In most cases, just printing the error is enough, but in this example, you would like to handle `ENOSPC` (no space left on device) explicitly. The `os` package returns an `*os.PathError` as error implementation in that case and if you want to access additional information about the error, i.e. everything beside the `Error() string`, method, you would have to convert it.

The statement `e, ok := err.(*os.PathError)` is a [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). It will check if the interface value `err` contains a `*os.PathError` as concrete type and will return that. If another type was stored in the interface (there might be other types that implement the `error` interface) then it will simply return the [zero value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) and false, i.e. `nil, false` in that case.

Answer (score 7):

From the [docs](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), that is a type assertion:

> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary expression

```
 x.(T)
```

> asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T. The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.